# How is the relative list item order calculated from tp_ItemOrder column?

Tags: column, sorting

I am using a custom action and the Reorder.aspx page to provide a sorting-functionality to my users. I followed the instructions that can be found here: https://niftit.com/blog/how-to-reorder-a-sharepoint-custom-list/

I managed to order my list by the "Order" column. However, i also want to display the order value. I found out that the reordering mechanism uses the tp_ItemOrder column and that the values that are stored there are responsible for calculating the relative order in which list items are displayed.

So my question is: How is the relative order calculated? If I display the "Order" column in my view the values are for example 162.5, 325, 350, 400, 500, 750 and so on. How can i calculate a meaningful numeration (1, 2, 3, 4, ...) from the values in the "Order" column?

Thanks for your help!